# Swi prolog finding all the neighbours of a nod in a directed graph

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I have a directed graph represented like this:

```
arc(1, 2).
arc(1, 4).
arc(1, 5).
arc(3, 2).
arc(3, 7).
arc(4, 3).
arc(5, 6).
arc(6, 8).
arc(7, 6).
arc(9, 8).
```

What I need is a predicate that will put inside a list all the nodes to which I can go from a specific node. For example for node 1 the resulted list should be `L=[2,4,5]` because from 1 I can go to 2,4 and 5. It doesn't matter how it is done, all it matters is the result, the nodes must be in a list.
I have tried to do this in a couple of ways but failed.

An example of how I tried to do it:

```
road(X,L,L2):- arc(X,Y), not(belong(Y,L)), append(L,[Y],L2), road(X,L2,_).   
road(X,L,L).
```

`belong(Y,L)` is a predicate that returns true if `Y` is found inside of `L`.
And for example when I run `road(1,[],L).` the result is `L=[2]`, which is normal because the predicate is not well written.
When I try make it using recursion I don't know what to put as the right stop for the recursion, I hope you understand what I want to say.
And I tried another way using fail but that didn't worked neither and I don't remember now how I made it.
I hope someone can come with a solution fast :), thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind to put in any attempted code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code need a fair amount of corrections: here is a working version.

```
road(X,L,L2) :- arc(X,Y), \+ memberchk(Y,L), !, road(X,[Y|L],L2).
road(_,L,L).
```

It must be called this way and will 'return' the list reversed

```
?- road(1,[],L).
L = [5, 4, 2] .
```

But it's much easier - and efficient - to use a builtin:

```
?- findall(Y, arc(1,Y), L).
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I tried the findall function before but I was using it wrong.